# Unable to create table in hive using Zeppelin

Tags: apache-spark, hive, amazon-emr, apache-zeppelin

I am running a query in `zeppelin` with spark interpreter to a create table.

```
spark.sql("create table person as select * from TABLE_NAME")
```

The query runs without any error.

But when I am running queries on that table I am getting this error

```
spark.sql("select count(*) from person")

: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: 
Task 30 in stage 80.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 30.3 in stage 80.0 (TID 7772, ip-10-226-34-88.ec2.internal, executor 530): 
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockMissingException: Could not obtain block: 
BP-97775991-10.226.34.113-1532420342496:blk_1073799259_58435 file=/user/hive/warehouse/person/part-0001
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

the issue is the format of the table - default is "parquet"
try changing it to "orc":

```
spark.sql("select * from TABLE_NAME").write.format("orc").saveAsTable("person")
```